# How do I make my navigation appear intact across different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, navigation

I am just starting out as a front-end developer and I noticed a lot things that I have to learn.  One of the key things is that my screen is currently 13 inches long so when I design it on that it looks perfect but when I go to a larger size, say 24 or higher the menu options look more aligned to the left than centered or the way they look on my screen size.

I am aware of cross-browser issues but never some thing like this.  Going forward, what's the best way to make sure that the site looks the same regardless of screen size? I will really appreciate any tips.  Thanks!

Comment: what does your current css and mark-up look like?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not a good idea to try to make "the site look the same regardless of screen size". First, *it will not look the same* and second it is a good idea to provide different styles for different screen sizes, especially very small ones (mobile).

When you search for "responsive design" you will find tons and tons of information about that. The most important thing though is to use relative units like `%` and `em` instead of absolute ones like `px`. And when you want to center things, have you tried `text-align: center;`?